# Updating position proportionally based on angle

Tags: objective-c, degrees

I'm strugling with this problem for some time and I couldn't find a similar topic, so...

1. An object (circle with a dot) rotates at a certain speed with a dot placed at 90 degrees (at the top)
2. When the dot reaches circle's 0 degrees the position resets to 90 degrees (for test purposes)
3. Another object (flag) is positioned at the meeting point with the dot
4. I have created a basic method to calculate the position of the flag based off the circle's degrees:

   ```
   -(CGPoint)positionOnArc 
   {
       CGFLoat posX = _circle.position.x + (arcRadius)*cos(degrees);
       CGFLoat posY = _circle.position.y + (arcRadius)*sin(degrees);
       return CGPointMake(posX, posY);
   }
   ```
5. Now the problem: How to force the flag to move at a slower pace than the circle? I want to achieve an effect in which for every 3 degrees of circle's movement, the flag moves by 1 degree.

Creating a second circle with the flag attached to it and basing the rotation speed on the speed of the first circle is out of the question. I need to make the flag's position 'stick and follow behind' the dot's degree point.

I know the answer may be painfully obvious but I just can't wrap it up in my head, so any hints would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I did manage to find a solution good enough for me, so I'm pasting it here as maybe it will help others new to programming like me when struglling with similar problems.

```
    -(CGPoint)positionOnArc
    {
        //Angle range between which the Dot is moving in percentages.
        CGFloat dotMovementRangePercentage = 100 * _circle.zRotation 
        - circleLeftAngleBoundary) / (circleRightAngleBoundary - 
        circleLeftAngleBoundary);
        //Degree on which the Flag is currently at.
        CGFloat flagPositionAnglePoint = ((flagLeftAngleBoundary 
        - flagRightAngleBoundary) * dotMovementRangePercentage) 
        + flagLeftAngleBoundary);

       //These two make sure that the flag will be moving slowly behind.
       if (flagPositionAnglePoint > 90) {
           flagPositionAnglePoint = flagPositionAnglePoint 
           - (1*(flagPositionAnglePoint/3 - 30));
       }
       if (flagPositionAnglePoint < 90) {
           flagPositionAnglePoint = flagPositionAnglePoint 
           + (1*(flagPositionAnglePoint/3 - 30));
       }

       //Final position is calculated here.
       CGFloat posX = _circle.position.x 
       - arcRadius*cos(-(flagPositionAnglePoint*M_PI)/180);
       CGFloat posY = _circle.position.y
       - arcRadius*sin(-(flagPositionAnglePoint*M_PI)/180);

       return CGPointMake(posX, posY);
    }
```

It may not be the best/most efficient/logical way to do it but I think it is something good enough to begin with.

Comment: Have you tried using `degrees/3.0` when calculating the position of the flag?

Comment: As far as I have tried this, when following your approach the initial position of the flag would change from 90 to 30 degrees. What I want to achieve is to get the feeling that the flag movement seems to be slower than the dot movement.

Comment: All further calculation could be 'circle with the dot' job, whereas the flag would update accordingly based on the circle's current degrees.
If I were to have two separate circles to which the flag and the dot were attached respectively, I could calculate their speed by dividing the degrees, however, in the long run it wouldn't be a good idea if I were to expand the logic.